# Reach and Frequency with Quicksight

Tags: formula, analytics, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to develop a reach and frequency report by territory in Quicksight. For example, a rep may have 10 customers that the need to visit 3 times in Q1. Looking for a way to show this reach for each rep. The issue is that someone my have visited a customer 4 times, so simply looking at a total of the visits would be inflated.

I tried developing a custom ifelse field to say if a count was > 3, put the output as 3. This worked on individual customer rows. However, when collapsing the data to look at a territory summary, the custom field applies to the subtotal and therefore does not work.

Here is what happening when I use this formula for the Adjusted Visits column
**ifelse(Current Visits < 4,Current Visits,3)**

```
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| Territory | Account | Visits Needed | Current Visits | Adjusted Visits | Reach % |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 99999     | Smith   | 3             | 4              | 3               | 100     |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 99999     | Jones   | 3             | 3              | 3               | 100%    |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 99999     | Max     | 3             | 3              | 3               | 100%    |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| SUBTOTAL  |         | 9             | 10             | 3               | 33%     |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
```

What I am looking for would be the following (essentially the subtotal ignoring the formula)

```
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| Territory | Account | Visits Needed | Current Visits | Adjusted Visits | Reach % |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 99999     | Smith   | 3             | 4              | 3               | 100     |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 99999     | Jones   | 3             | 3              | 3               | 100%    |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 99999     | Max     | 3             | 3              | 3               | 100%    |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| SUBTOTAL  |         | 9             | 10             | 9               | 100%    |
+-----------+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+---------+
```